# Private route (react gatsby) render before able to retrieve user information for authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, gatsby, mern

Once I validated user's token, I will set user information into localStorage. The "isLoggedIn()" function will retrieve the user information to decide whether the user should proceed or not.

The problem that I encounter is private route would render first before the information is set into localStorage, so "isLoggedIn()" function will return empty localStorage first and I have to reload/refresh in order to login successfully.

Below are my code fragment, this project is very important to me, and I have to get it done asap. I do hope I can get any help from anyone. Thank you guys in advance.

**Index.js**

```
const Index = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={Upload} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/agents" component={Agents} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/statistics" component={Statistics} />
        <Login path="/login" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )

}
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {

  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/login`) {
    navigate("/login")
    return null
  }
  return <Component {...rest} />
}
```

**Auth.js**

```
export const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined"

export const getUser = () =>
  isBrowser() && window.localStorage.getItem("user")
    ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"))
    : {}

export const setUser = user =>
  window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user))


export const handleLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {

  const loginUser = { email, password };
  const loginResponse = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/users/login", loginUser);
  if (loginResponse) {
    localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginResponse.data.token);

    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
    if (token === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
      token = "";
    }
    const tokenResponse = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/tokenIsValid', null, { headers: { "x-auth-token": token } });
    if (tokenResponse.data) {
      const userRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/", {
        headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
      });
      
      return setUser({
        username: userRes.data.displayName
      })
    }
  }

  return false
}

export const isLoggedIn = () => {

  const user = getUser();
  return !!user.username;

}

export const logout = callback => {
  setUser({})
  localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
  callback()
}
```

**loginComponent.js**

```
class loginComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    //sessionStay: "false"
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    handleLogin(this.state)
   
  }
  render() {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        navigate(`/`)
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="login-component-wrapper">
        <img src={logo} className="login-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h2>Agent Reporting Dashboard</h2>
        <form className="login-form">
          <div className="login-form-wrapper">
            <label className="form-field-label" htmlFor="email">
              Email:{" "}
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-field"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
              }}
              onKeyPress={e => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  this.handleSubmit(e)
                  navigate(`/`)
                }
              }}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
            <label className="form-field-label" htmlFor="password">
              Password:{" "}
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-field"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
              }}
              onKeyPress={e => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  this.handleSubmit(e)
                  navigate(`/`)
                }
              }}
              value={this.state.password}
            />
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="session-stay"
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({ sessionStay: e.target.value })
              }}
              value="true"
            />
            <label className="form-field-label" htmlFor="session-stay">
              Keep me logged in
            </label>
            <br />
            <button
              type="button"
              className="login-button btn-primary"
              onClick={event => {
                this.handleSubmit(event)
                navigate(`/`)
              }}
            >
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disk actions (like setting `localStorage`) are asynchronous because it takes some time to be performed, depending on the PC, network, etc.

Without a CodeSandbox it's difficult to guess how the code will behave but to me, it seems a matter of asynchronous. You can make some trials adding something like:

```
export const handleLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {

  const loginUser = { email, password };
  const loginResponse = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/users/login", loginUser);
  if (loginResponse) {
    await localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginResponse.data.token);

    let token = await localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
    if (token === null) {
      await  localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
      token = "";
    }
    const tokenResponse = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/tokenIsValid', null, { headers: { "x-auth-token": token } });
    if (tokenResponse.data) {
      const userRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/", {
        headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
      });
      
      return setUser({
        username: userRes.data.displayName
      })
    }
  }

  return false
}
```

Note the `await` inside the async `handleLogin` function.

Comment: I personally also think it's a matter of asynchronous, but then I tried your method it still can't work, the private route still render first by getting the empty localStorage, and then the user info only went in to the localStorage so when I refresh, the private route render again and this time it detects the user info in localStorage. Thank you for trying to help, is there another way to fix it? I try to avoid using setTimeOut

Comment: I would try adding setTimeout methods in order to get which function is causing this behavior, just debug. As soon as you detect it, I would try to fix with an elegant workaround

Comment: yea i did tried put a setTimeout method inside a useEffect hook, then i place my entire if statement from my PrivateRoute.js inside the setTimeout function where i delay it for 500 millisecond, and while it loading I display a loading screen. By doing so it works well, so i guess the problem is private route will render first and "isLoggedIn()" function will run before the user info is set inside localStorage, but until now I still can't find a way to solve it